# Can't remove PDF file from cache Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, caching

I'm using the following library to display a pdf in my application "https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer".

I'm displaying the pdf from file assets like this:

```
loadDocument() async {
    document = await PDFDocument.fromAsset('assets/res/sample.pdf');

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

The problem is that I want to replace the file with a new version, but it keeps showing the old one.

What I tried:

1- Changing file name

2- Flutter clean

3- Pub get

4- Deleting the whole file from the project, and still showing ( which means it's somewhere in the cache )

5- Deleting the app

All previous solutions didn't work, and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks